# Salesforce and Informatica cloud dala loader not getting connected

Tags: migration-tool, informatica

I'm using Informatica Cloud data loader to export data from Salesforce to external csv file.
 I'm trying to make a connection with Salesforce but geting this error:

"The login to Salesforce.com failed with the following message - com.sforce.soap.partner.LoginFault: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out."

I am sure my credentials are correct.

I have installed secure agent to communicate with local files and that's working fine.

but facing error while connecting with Salesforce(developers version).

can anyone help ?

Comment: When signing into dataload.io no security token is needed. Are you including your token?

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked Login history of user , does it show there? If no, then may be username is not correct or Server is not correct (Sandbox, Production, MyDomain).

If it shows there, then recheck Password and Security token. Many time it seems that password is correct but it may have extra space at end while copy paste.
To my knowledge I dont see any known issue to Login Salesforce, Our integration is working fine.

Also just to check (`but not recommended`), you can disable security token on your developer edition by adding Login IP range on your profile and try to connect just with your password.